# Use GET params to provide the Web interface with a specific text to annotate

Tags: stanford-nlp, corenlp-server

I would like to link to my instance of CoreNLP server, with a specified text (and possibly, a specified set of annotators). (i.e. without having to paste the text then click on Submit)

Is there a way to do this?

(I know and use the API version, but I'm looking for the Web visualisation)

Comment: I don't think that is possible at this time...

Comment: You want a url like "localhost:9000/q=quick+brown+fox+jumped+over+fence;annotators=tokenize...etc..." and it will load the visualization browser with those values, correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, answering my own question: this is now possible (I believe from CoreNlp 3.8), after a successfully merged pull request from yours truly.

This is the relevant pull request: https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/pull/423

Answer (score 0):

No, the current visualization doesn't let you specify text in the URL (though pull requests are always welcome; the source code lives [here](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/tree/master/src/edu/stanford/nlp/pipeline/demo)).

The server does respond to regular POST requests, e.g., if you want to call CoreNLP from your own webpage though Javascript. For example, the given curl command (from [the documentation page](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/corenlp-server.html):

```
curl --data 'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.' 'http://localhost:9000/?properties={%22annotators%22%3A%22tokenize%2Cssplit%2Cpos%22%2C%22outputFormat%22%3A%22json%22}' -o -
```

The visualization is done with more or less vanilla [brat](http://brat.nlplab.org/features.html).

Comment: I think what he actually wants is a url he can submit which will load the visualization page in the browser with the annotators set and the query text, which I don't think is possible at this time...

Comment: Oh yes, it's not currently possible to issue a query in the web frontend on loading the page. Pull requests are always welcome though :)

Comment: Isn't the text to annotate always being sent via POST currently?

Comment: Yes, you're right. So both halves of my answer are wrong. Editing appropriately.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Pull request submitted there: https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/pull/423